# Flutter Dismissible insists list item must be removed from tree

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using a list of Dismissible items and want a swipe in one direction to delete the item but a swipe in the other direction to initiate an edit of the item.  However, Flutter insists that a Dismissible item must be removed from the tree in the onDismissed callback.  I've tried re-inserting the item but that doesn't work.  Any ideas?  Extract from the code creating the list items is below:

```
  return new Dismissible(
    key: new ObjectKey(item),
    direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
    onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
      setState(() {
        item.deleteTsk();
      });
      if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart){
        //user swiped left to delete item
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
          content: new Text('You deleted: ${item.title}'),
          action: new SnackBarAction(
            label: 'UNDO',
            onPressed: () { handleUndo(item); }
          )
        ));
      }
      if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd){
        //user swiped right to edit so undo the delete required by flutter
        Async.scheduleMicrotask((){handleUndo(item);});
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/tskedit');
      }
    },
  ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Dismissible` will think your item was dismissed as long as the item key changes. Let's say your item class is `MyItem`. If you implement a constructor `MyItem.from` in your `MyItem` class that copies the fields over, e.g.:

```
class MyItem {
  MyItem({ @required this.title, @required this.color });
  MyItem.from(MyItem other) : title = other.title, color = other.color;
  final String title;
  final Color color;
}
```

Then you can replace `handleUndo(item)` with `handleUndo(new MyItem.from(item))` so that your `new ObjectKey(item)` will be unique from the old `ObjectKey` that you used before (assuming you didn't implement `operator ==` on `MyItem`).

Comment: Genius - thanks!  More generally, its a bit strange that a work around like this is needed at all.  I would have thought my use case was not that unusual.

Comment: I agree that this use case for `Dismissible` is awkward. Feel free to [file an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new) if you have a suggestion for a better behavior.

Comment: Hey is it possible to implement the Dismissible functionality for an OnTap Gesture instead of Swipe?

Answer (score 29):

You can use `confirmDismiss` function of `Dismissible` widget for this purpose.

If you don't want the widget to get dismissed, then you just need to return `false` from `confirmDismiss`.

Don't use `onDismissed` to do your post-swipe processing, use `confirmDismiss` instead, it will provide you with the swipe direction just as `onDismissed`.

Here is the official documentation for `confirmDismiss` function:

> Gives the app an opportunity to confirm or veto a pending dismissal.
>       If the returned Future completes true, then this widget will be
>       dismissed, otherwise it will be moved back to its original location.
>       If the returned Future completes to false or null the [onResize]

and here is an example:

```
Dismissible(
  confirmDismiss: (direction) async {
    if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
      /// edit item
      return false;
    } else if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
      /// delete
      return true;
    }
  },
  key: Key(item.key),
  child: Text(item.name),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With confirmDismiss you are still left in animation hell...
Recommend checking out this Flutter core issue that aims to use an animation with Duration.zero instead: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29844